# adding data dynamicaly to an activity in android

Tags: android

### How to add data dynamically to an activity in android

- when i select one row1 in listview(`mainActivity.xml`) -> i need to
  populate data W.R.T that row in another activity `new_act.xml` from a
  server ( I am getting data from server as JSON response )
- similarly when i select row2 in listview(`mainActivity.xml`) -. i
  need to populate data  W.R.T that row in same new activity say
  `new_act.xml` from a server

*so here i am using only 2 activities `mainActivity.xml` for list view and `new_act.xml` to display data*

**which android concepts should i refer**

should i need to refer Fragremts ?

**i am building android app only for mobile devices not tablets**

Any Ideas

**Thanks**

Comment: `i am building android app only for mobile devices not tablets` why? take a look here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Design and here http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/tablets-and-handsets.html

Comment: I am trying to learn dynamic data display for an activity ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass data to another activity by storing the data as `Intent extras`.  Start by looking at these methods: [Intent Extras](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra%28java.lang.String,%20double%5B%5D%29)

So you would build your Intent to start the `new_act` Activity like so:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, new_act.class);
i.putExtra("key", "value");
startActivity(i);
```

And then in your `new_act` Activity in `onCreate()` you would get that data like so:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstaceState) {
    ...
    String value = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
}
```

So I'm assuming to do what you want you will have to implement an OnItemClickListener for your ListView in the first activity.  Then when an item is clicked, you will build an Intent to your second activity with whatever data you want to pass through.

Comment: Good Info ... Hey are you suggesting like since Url is taken as input by an activity for displaying a data obtained from server ...... make a condition in listactivity and based on that condition result pass the url as string to the next activity using onitem click ... with the help of intents ?

Comment: @Sky Yes, exactly.  You have a couple approaches.  You can load the data from the URL as you load each ListView item and then pass the data to the next Activity.  Or you can (like you suggested) simply pass the URL to the next Activity and fetch your data there.  With OnItemClickListener, it will pass you a position variable which you can use to get the corresponding object at that index from your ListView to do all of this.